# AS3/Flash: Difference of dates in milliseconds to days?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, date, milliseconds

How do I get the difference in days between two dates formated as milliseconds. I.E.:

```
1377750038984 - 1329361285663 = xdays
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var milliseconds = 1377750038984 - 1329361285663;    
var days = Math.floor( (milliseconds / (1000*60*60*24)) );
```

Comment: I did forget to tell: In my case It's better to get the rational number.